# Import existing photo at smaller size - phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova

Using Phonegap and android, I'm getting a user to take a photo, then displaying a preview to them:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src= imageUri;
$("#dialogContent").prepend(img);
```

It works fine. However on powerful modern phones with super powerful cameras [like the Galaxy S3] this crashes the app due to the file size.

What I want, is to be able to import the photo I've taken at a smaller size, but keep the original photo full size (as I'm going to upload it).

Something like this:

```
var maxSize = Math.max(screen.width, screen.height);
targetHeight: maxSize,
targetWidth: maxSize,
```

Is there a way of using **"navigator.camera.getPicture"** if you already know the fileURI?

Answer (score -1):

```
File  file=new File("your path");

Bitmap screen = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file);             
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
screen.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 15, bytes);
```

Comment: That looks good, but it also looks like it's Java, I'm using Phonegap (which uses JS to hook into some android apis).